# unexpected end of json input error when I try to create a react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npx

I keep getting the error of unexpected end of json input when I run the command "npx create-react app". below is the error message:

error An unexpected error occurred: "C:\Users\Josh\AppData\Local\Yarn\Cache\v6\npm-@svgr-babel-plugin-add-jsx-attribute-5.4.0-81ef61947bb268eb9d50523446f9c638fb355906-integrity\node_modules\@svgr\babel-plugin-add-jsx-attribute\.yarn-metadata.json: Unexpected end of JSON input".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\Users\Josh\Documents\edconnect-react\tic-tac-toe\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...

Please how do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the yarn cache with `yarn cache clean`?

Comment: I tried that now and it worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As noted above `yarn cache clean` should deal with most issues. However, today I came across this situation and none of these worked for me:

```bash
yarn cache clean
yarn cache clean --force
yarn cache clean --mirror
yarn cache clean --all
```

The issue was that by running npx, or perhaps an npm/yarn command earlier there was a package.json file that was created in my home directory with nothing in it

by removing this file via

```bash
rm ~/package.json
```

yarn (and npx commands that invoke yarn) were able to run successfully in my project